# How to get a Value from a Qtable

Tags: python, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

i have an editable row in my tablewidget. The values are from a .txt.
My intension is it to change some Values in the widget, and then make a new .txt with the changed Values. but i dont know how to "extract" the changed Values from the widget.

with

```
item=self.model.item(1,1)
iteml.append(item)
print(iteml)
```

I only get:

```
[<PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem object at 0x02DD2A98>]
```

But I don't want the memory address but the Value. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding on top of Mailerdaimon: If you want the string as a python string instead of a PyQt4.QtCore.QString object, you can simply use

```
item=self.model.item(1,1)
thestring = str(item.text())
```

(Sorry, I would have posted a comment, but I'm not allowed since I don't have 50 rep.)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
item=self.model.item(1,1)
item.text()
```

to get the Text Value of the [QTableWidgetItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html)

Comment: if i use `print(item.text())` i get the Value, but if I add "item.text())" to a list, with `list.append(item.text())` i get "[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'Value')"... why?

Comment: if you add the item (not the string) to a list `print list[i].text()` should work